# Find Values in an unsorted array

Tags: arrays, binary-search

I need to find out all the combinations of sum of any two numbers in an array. if it is equal then print them. 
The linear solution to this problem has O(N^2) complexity. 
I thought of sorting and then doing a binary comparison. The complexity is still (NlogN + N)

The problem is I need to find all the combinations of it.

A linear solution to this problem
Eg.

```
//Linear search, find all the combinations
Find(int a[], int Target)
    {
       for(i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
            for(j=0; j<arr_size; j++)
                if((a[i]+a[j]) == Target)
                     cout<<a[i]<<a[j]
     }
```

Is there any way to reduce the complexity further?

Thanks,
Guru

Comment: "The complexity is still (NlogN + N)" - what's wrong with a complexity of O(NlogN)??

Comment: Linear solution should have `if(i!=j && (a[i]+a[j]) == Target)`. I'm not clear how sorting helps, given that then you have the added complexity of the sort itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could first filter out all impossibilities. This should only need two iterations through the array and has the potential to dramatically reduce the set. If it doesn't, well you have only lost 2 iterations.

For starters, you could find your least number, then filter out all values > (target - least number).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly improved the performance

```
private static void find(int[] a, int target) {

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == target) {
            System.out.println("result found");
            break;
        }
        if (a[i] > target) {
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if ((i != j && (a[i] + a[j]) == target)) {
                System.out.println("result found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you assuming that all elements of the set are non-negative?

Comment: Yes, Assuming array containg positive values.

Comment: allowing for negatives, you would have to use my algorithm above. Anyhow, it's the same idea.